How to show labels at front and last points after geom_smooth using geom_dl?
This question refers to generic problem but my code set is very much different and most of the solutions give are basically work-around. So, I also need a little help in tagging lables next to beginning and end of 'geom_smooth' line.
The labels are diplayed at a distance making it confusing especially when there are minor differences in the colors of lines.
My code is
    ggplot(tbl5, aes(x=reorder(TRDAY, -TRORDER), y=AVMKTPC, col=SYMBOL, group = SYMBOL)) + 
        geom_smooth(se=F, linewidth=1) + 
        theme(legend.position="none") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1, hjust=-1)) +
        scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0, 3)) +
        scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(min(tbl5$MN), max(tbl5$MN), by = round((max(tbl5$MN)-min(tbl5$MN))/10, 0))) +
        geom_dl(aes(label = SYMBOL), method = list(dl.combine("first.points", "last.points")), cex = 1)  +
        theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#030905")) +
        theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
        facet_wrap( ~ GRP, ncol=4, scales = "free_y") +
        xlab("Days") + ylab("Price Range") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .9, vjust = -240),
              panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "skyblue", linetype = "dotted", linewidth = .2)) + #y value is different for zoom (220) and export
        geom_vline(xintercept = c(clo[38], clo[12]), color = "red", linetype = "dotted")

My data for tbl5 is
structure(list(SYMBOL = c("SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", 
"SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", 
"SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", 
"SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", 
"SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", 
"SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "SDL24BEES", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", 
"HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", 
"HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", 
"HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", 
"HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", 
"HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "HDFCSENSEX", "TNIDETF", 
"TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", 
"TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", 
"TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", 
"TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", "TNIDETF", 
"TNIDETF", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", 
"AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", 
"AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", 
"AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", 
"AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "AXSENSEX", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", 
"SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", 
"SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", 
"SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", 
"SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", 
"SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXADD", "SENSEXETF", 
"SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", 
"SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", 
"SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", 
"SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", 
"SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", "SENSEXETF", 
"BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", 
"BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", 
"BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", 
"BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", 
"BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", "BSLSENETFG", 
"BSLSENETFG", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", 
"GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", 
"GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", 
"GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", 
"GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD", 
"GOLDETFADD", "GOLDETFADD"), TRDAY = c("Jun12", "Jun10", "Jun06", 
"Jun04", "May31", "May29", "May27", "May23", "May21", "May16", 
"May14", "May10", "May08", "May06", "May02", "Apr29", "Apr25", 
"Apr23", "Apr19", "Apr16", "Apr12", "Apr09", "Apr05", "Apr03", 
"Apr01", "Mar27", "Jun12", "Jun10", "Jun06", "Jun04", "May31", 
"May29", "May27", "May23", "May21", "May16", "May14", "May10", 
"May08", "May06", "May02", "Apr29", "Apr25", "Apr23", "Apr19", 
"Apr16", "Apr12", "Apr09", "Apr05", "Apr03", "Apr01", "Mar27", 
"Jun12", "Jun10", "Jun06", "Jun04", "May31", "May29", "May27", 
"May23", "May21", "May16", "May14", "May10", "May08", "May06", 
"May02", "Apr29", "Apr25", "Apr23", "Apr19", "Apr16", "Apr12", 
"Apr09", "Apr05", "Apr03", "Apr01", "Mar27", "Jun12", "Jun10", 
"Jun06", "Jun04", "May31", "May29", "May27", "May23", "May21", 
"May16", "May14", "May10", "May08", "May06", "May02", "Apr29", 
"Apr25", "Apr23", "Apr19", "Apr16", "Apr12", "Apr09", "Apr05", 
"Apr03", "Apr01", "Mar27", "Jun12", "Jun10", "Jun06", "Jun04", 
"May31", "May29", "May27", "May23", "May21", "May16", "May14", 
"May10", "May08", "May06", "May02", "Apr29", "Apr25", "Apr23", 
"Apr19", "Apr16", "Apr12", "Apr09", "Apr05", "Apr03", "Apr01", 
"Mar27", "Jun12", "Jun10", "Jun06", "Jun04", "May31", "May29", 
"May27", "May23", "May21", "May16", "May14", "May10", "May08", 
"May06", "May02", "Apr29", "Apr25", "Apr23", "Apr19", "Apr16", 
"Apr12", "Apr09", "Apr05", "Apr03", "Apr01", "Mar27", "Jun12", 
"Jun10", "Jun06", "Jun04", "May31", "May29", "May27", "May23", 
"May21", "May16", "May14", "May10", "May08", "May06", "May02", 
"Apr29", "Apr25", "Apr23", "Apr19", "Apr16", "Apr12", "Apr09", 
"Apr05", "Apr03", "Apr01", "Mar27", "Jun12", "Jun10", "Jun06", 
"Jun04", "May31", "May29", "May27", "May23", "May21", "May16", 
"May14", "May10", "May08", "May06", "May02", "Apr29", "Apr25", 
"Apr23", "Apr19", "Apr16", "Apr12", "Apr09", "Apr05", "Apr03", 
"Apr01", "Mar27"), AVMKTPC = c(122.04, 121.73, 121.58, 121.51, 
121.57, 121.74, 121.67, 121.77, 121.69, 121.18, 121.14, 121.09, 
121.02, 120.93, 120.9, 120.77, 120.6, 120.33, 120.28, 120.34, 
120.32, 120.23, 120.35, 120.14, 120.03, 120.07, 85.06, 84.64, 
83.42, 84.4, 82.91, 82.67, 83.32, 82.94, 81.98, 81.38, 80.62, 
80.39, 81.01, 81.57, 82.19, 82.06, 81.75, 81.38, 80.66, 80.55, 
81.98, 82.62, 82, 81.55, 81.37, 80.4, 81.82, 81.28, 79.38, 77.63, 
77.56, 78.45, 79.71, 79.99, 79.64, 78.73, 77.56, 77.37, 77.95, 
78.24, 78.87, 79.18, 78.92, 78.41, 78.03, 78.77, 80.79, 81.53, 
80.89, 80.03, 79.47, 78.76, 77.49, 77.49, 76.51, 76.39, 75.34, 
75.32, 76.21, 75.7, 74.9, 73.92, 73.85, 73.46, 73.77, 74.52, 
74.97, 74.89, 74.79, 74.48, 73.74, 73.57, 74.76, 75.35, 74.93, 
74.56, 74.49, 73.5, 76.8, 76.78, 77.5, 77.01, 75.4, 75.11, 75.7, 
75.07, 74.38, 73.9, 73.47, 74, 74.51, 73.99, 74.47, 74.47, 74.62, 
74.62, 73.65, 73.38, 74.57, 75.04, 74.67, 74.15, 73.51, 72.97, 
77.34, 77.23, 75.96, 76.39, 76.06, 75.66, 75.84, 75.44, 74.62, 
74.1, 73.63, 73.29, 73.31, 73.98, 74.69, 74.39, 74.36, 74.55, 
73.38, 73.44, 74.51, 75.04, 74.63, 74.28, 73.99, 73.41, 75.48, 
75.29, 74.15, 74.29, 73.48, 73.4, 74.04, 73.58, 73.07, 72.26, 
71.7, 71.32, 71.8, 72.36, 73.13, 73, 72.54, 71.92, 71.37, 71.5, 
72.76, 73.3, 73.03, 72.62, 72.66, 71.59, 70.98, 71, 71.6, 71.22, 
71.39, 71.58, 71.44, 72.26, 73.19, 72.62, 71.93, 71.63, 70.92, 
70.89, 71.01, 71.65, 71.45, 71.24, 72.52, 72.24, 71.63, 70.83, 
69.52, 68.74, 67.74, 66.19), GRP = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), COL = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), TRORDER = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L), MN = c(89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 
89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 
89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 
89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 
89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 
89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 
89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 73, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -208L), groups = structure(list(
    GRP = c(1, 2), .rows = structure(list(1:104, 105:208), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))

In the code there is a variable clo whose data is pasted below.
clo <- c("Jun13", "Jun12", "Jun11", "Jun10", "Jun07", "Jun06", "Jun05", 
"Jun04", "Jun03", "May31", "May30", "May29", "May28", "May27", 
"May24", "May23", "May22", "May21", "May17", "May16", "May15", 
"May14", "May13", "May10", "May09", "May08", "May07", "May06", 
"May03", "May02", "Apr30", "Apr29", "Apr26", "Apr25", "Apr24", 
"Apr23", "Apr22", "Apr19", "Apr18", "Apr16", "Apr15", "Apr12", 
"Apr10", "Apr09", "Apr08", "Apr05", "Apr04", "Apr03", "Apr02", 
"Apr01", "Mar28", "Mar27", "Mar26")


The issue is that geom_dl uses stat="identity", i.e. the labels are placed on the raw data values not the smoothed ones. And unfortunately geom_dl does not allow to use stat="smooth" (see this GH issue).
Instead a workaround mentioned by the package author is to use direct.label() (see here).
Note: For other approaches see e.g. Add direct labels to geom_smooth rather than geom_line.
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)

gg <- ggplot(tbl5, aes(
  x = reorder(TRDAY, -TRORDER), y = AVMKTPC,
  color = SYMBOL, group = SYMBOL
)) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, linewidth = 1) +
  geom_vline(
    xintercept = c(clo[38], clo[12]),
    color = "red", linetype = "dotted"
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 3)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(min(tbl5$MN), max(tbl5$MN),
                 by = round((max(tbl5$MN) - min(tbl5$MN)) / 10, 0)
    )
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~GRP, ncol = 4, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#030905"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(
      colour = "skyblue",
      linetype = "dotted", linewidth = .2
    ),
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1, hjust = 0)
  ) +
  xlab("Days") +
  ylab("Price Range") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")

direct.label(gg, method = list(dl.combine("first.points", "last.points")))
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'


